# How to require parameters in action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to validate that a parameter is present in the action.

```
public string PorCarrera([Required] DateTime fechaDesde, [Required] DateTime fechaHasta, string carrera = null) {
            return InformacionInscripcionesViewModel.GetTotalesInscripcionesPorCarrera(fechaDesde, fechaHasta, carrera);
        }
```

I would expect the framework to throw a `BadRequest` when calling the action without parameters but it is not happening.

All examples talk about `modelState.IsValid` but I don't have any model that represents this data, because these are just queries to a DB.

Comment: Useful article for querystring http://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/required-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to is make a *model* to represent your parameters. Something like this:

```
public class PorCarreraModel
{
    [Required]
    DateTime fechaDesde { get; set; }
    [Required]
    DateTime fechaHasta { get; set; }
    string carrera { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can make your controller action like this:

```
public IActionResult PorCarrera(PorCarreraModel model) {
     if(ModelState.IsValid == false)
     {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
     string totals = InformacionInscripcionesViewModel.GetTotalesInscripcionesPorCarrera(model.fechaDesde, model.fechaHasta, model.carrera);
     return Content(totals);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a shame that the framework does not have this by default. Or even throwing a Bad Request error is a pain because it does not have this functionality

Comment: Well you could always build an action filter that does that and apply it globally.