# How to require parameters in asp.net actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to require/validate parameters for actions. Right now I have lot of actions that looks like this (which is horrible):

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string paramA, string paramB, string paramC)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramA))
    {
        return JsonResult(false, "paramA is missing");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramB))
    {
        return JsonResult(false, "paramB is missing");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paramC))
    {
        return JsonResult(false, "paramC is missing");
    }

    //Actual Code
}
```

How to encapsulte this (potentially "globally")? I know that its possible to wrap parameters to model and use ModelState.IsValid like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39538103/766304
That is maybe one step forward on same places but generally I don't that it's realistic to wrap all parameters to models everywhere (~1 class definition per 1 action method... how nice is that?).

Also this is again per action ceremony which should be handled somewhere centralized:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to validate models within ASP.NET MVC and return errors backs.  Is there something specific that you need help with?

Comment: Nice to hear. Could you give some example/keyword/link to some non-per-action way?

Comment: Well when googling "request validation" there is lot of stuff about validating request against potentially harmfull content, like string parameters containing HTML but this is not a case. My question with another words: I am looking way to customize how to match request and invoking action method.

Comment: What do you mean by match them?  You want to google 'ASP.NET MVC model validation'

Comment: If request dosen't contain paramC in any form, "DoSomething" action method will invoked with paramC setted to null. I think it shouldn't be invoked at all and instead of get handled some global error handler. Just like its illegal to call this method with C# code: action.DoSomething("A", "B"); <-- Won't even compile because it dosen't make sense.

Comment: The answer by Lukasz will do this.  Decorating your model with validation attributes and checking the model state will allow you to do this.  This is that way that you do it in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do it would be to create a model class and use `[Required]` attributes like this:

```
public class FooModel 
{
   [Required]
   public string ParamA {get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string ParamB {get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string ParamC {get;set;}
}
```

And then use it in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(FooModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // return some errors based on ModelState
    }

    //Actual Code
}
```

If you are looking for more global approach, then i believe you could look into Action Filters and use OnActionExecuting filter and handle the validation there (haven't used that myself tho).
Here is how to do it: 
[How can I centralize modelstate validation in asp.net mvc using action filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654669/how-can-i-centralize-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-using-action-filters)
That way your method would never be called if any of the parameters were missing.

Comment: This won't solve problem with non model parameters but checking ModelState from ActionFilter is good idea so +1.

Comment: Well you can always add whatever properties you want to your model and add another attributes for them or even write custome ones for properties or even whole classes.

Answer (score 0):

The model annotations with [Required] [Length] and all these attributes is one of the most common ways to validate your model, specially it integrates with the Razor View engine and generates JavaScript validation as well, the same will happen if you are using EntityFramework for your back end, so this way you will have validation at the level of the UI, Controller and Data access.

You can also use Code Contracts which allows you to put pre and post conditions for your method in a nice way https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx

If none of the above is still not enough, then you can add some checks in either your controller action or in your business domain service to make some business validation and return an error code if any errors found

Comment: Code Contracts may be cleaner way to do some validation but I don't see how these things help me to solve missing parameter problem _globally_.

Comment: If you require a parameter to have a value then an exception will be thrown and the code will not execute.
Another approach would be to use Routing Constrains, this will prevent the action from being invoked if the parameter was not present